# Nuxt: Set origin on all Axios requests, depending on currenct domain

Tags: vue.js, proxy, axios, nuxt.js

I'm making proxy requests using [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module). This is set up in nuxt.config.js and works just fine.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
proxy: {
  '/api/': {
    target: 'api.example.com',
    headers: {
      'origin': 'www.example.com',
      // ...
    },
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api/': ''
    }
  },
}
// ...
```

However, I'd like to make the origin dynamic - so it depends on the current domain. So I removed the header from nuxt.config.js and instead created this plugin. Just to test I've hardcoded the same origin as I did in the nuxt.config.js

`plugins/origin.js`

```js
export default function (ctx) {    
  ctx.$axios.onRequest(config => {
    config.headers['origin'] = 'www.example.com';
    return config;
  }, err => console.log(err));
}
```

This doesn't work. The API log tells me that I need to set the origin, but that's what I did, right? The only idea I have is: Because this is a proxy request, the headers are not transferred somehow.

**Update**

I am server side rendering and the plugin is added in `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/origin.js'
]
```

Comment: Are you doing any server side rendering? Plugins will not run anytime you do an axios request ... where do you call your plugin, and when do you call your plugin?

Comment: why do you use onRequest function and not give the headers directly to axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

I removed the plugin and instead I added `onProxyReq` method in the `nuxt.config.js`

```
proxy: {
  '/api/': {
    target: 'api.example.com',
    headers: {
      'origin': 'www.example.com',
      // ...
    },
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api/': ''
    },
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
      proxyReq.setHeader('origin', 'www.example.com')
    }
  },
}
// ...
```